# Populate PHP multidimensional array from $_POST

Tags: php, arrays

I have to build an array as the following one gathering values from $_POST superglobal. ca_objets value would be gather from a variable and the part after the dot is what I need to gather from $_POST.

```
 $va_body=array(
        "bundles" => array(
            "ca_objects.description" => array("convertCodesToDisplayText" => true),
            "ca_objects.description" => array("convertCodesToDisplayText" => true),
            "ca_object.representations.caption" => array("convertCodesToDisplayText" =>  true)
        )
    );
```

This is the code I use:

```
<?php
$table="ca_objects";
$bund=$_POST['find_bundles']; //This is an array with the values I need.

$va_body=array("bundles" => array()); //I declare the array outside the foreach loop.
```

I'm not sure how to code the loop in order to populate the "bundles" array inside $va_body array and get the result I need. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
   foreach ($bund as $elem ) {
    // code here
        }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just access the array by its associative key, like this:

```
foreach ($bund as $elem ) {
    // code here
    // The empty square brackets tells php to push the $elem value into the next available array key
    $va_body['bundles'][] = $elem;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's really useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value after the dots as the new key, you need to split the string. So if you use a foreach loop of the form: `foreach($array as $key => $value)` you split the values after the dots

```
   foreach ($bund as $elem => $value) {
        $strings = explode('.', $elem); // Split the strings at the dot
        $ca_objects[$bundles][$strings[count(strings) - 1]] = $value; // Add to array with $elem => $value
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a comprehensive answer! I'm sure I'll succeed with it.